# Jquery conflicting causing jquery on other pages not to work

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

i'm trying to make a parallax effect on a site however the jquery between two pages seems to be conflicting. On the home page when you scroll down all the elements move in just like they should, but when you go to the work page and scroll down nothing happens. here is the Jquery as is(i'll leave the comments out of the code-block for ease of reading):

```
$('document').ready(function() {

$('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-animate');
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-animate');
  $('.page-contents').toggleClass('page-contents-animate');

});

});



$(window).scroll(function(){

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.logo').css({
'transform' : 'translate(0px , '+ wScroll /40 +'rem)'
});
```

//HOME PAGE SCRIPT

```
if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 6 )) {
$('.about h1').addClass('about-h1-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.about h1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 3.5 )) {
$('.about p').addClass('about-h1-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.about h1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2.5 )) {
$('.about').addClass('about-bg-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top) {
$('.symbol').each(function(i){

setTimeout(function(){
$('.symbol').eq(i).addClass('social-is-showing');},
150 * (i+3));
});
}//END HOME PAGE SCRIPT
```

//WORK PAGE SCRIPT

```
if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 10 )) {
$('.amorae-desktop').addClass('amorae-desktop-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.amoraeWork').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 12 )) {
$('.amorae-tablet').addClass('amorae-tablet-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.amoraeWork').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 8 )) {
$('.amorae-phone').addClass('amorae-phone-is-showing');
}//END WORK PAGE SCRIPT


});
```

I've tried a lot of things and when I move the 'WORK PAGE SCRIPT' above the 'HOME PAGE SCRIPT' the work page starts working but the home page doesn't. I really don't know why this is happening. I have tried making a new function for the work page below the home page script but still had the same issue.

I found a way to get them both working which was by moving the 'WORK PAGE SCRIPT' above the 'HOME PAGE SCRIPT' and changing the window scroll offset class to .logo

It's not ideal though as I want to learn what the problem is and know how to fix it. been driving me mad for a couple of days now so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. The work around code is below along with a link to the live site. Thanks.

```
$('document').ready(function() {

$('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggle-animate');
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-animate');
  $('.page-contents').toggleClass('page-contents-animate');

});

});



$(window).scroll(function(){

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.logo').css({
'transform' : 'translate(0px , '+ wScroll /40 +'rem)'
});

//WORK PAGE SCRIPT

if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 10 )) {
$('.amorae-desktop').addClass('amorae-desktop-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 12 )) {
$('.amorae-tablet').addClass('amorae-tablet-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 8 )) {
$('.amorae-phone').addClass('amorae-phone-is-showing');
}//END WORK PAGE SCRIPT
```

//HOME PAGE SCRIPT

```
if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 6 )) {
$('.about h1').addClass('about-h1-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.about h1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 3.5 )) {
$('.about p').addClass('about-h1-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.about h1').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2.5 )) {
$('.about').addClass('about-bg-is-showing');
}

if(wScroll > $('.logo').offset().top) {
$('.symbol').each(function(i){

setTimeout(function(){
$('.symbol').eq(i).addClass('social-is-showing');},
150 * (i+3));
});
}//END HOME PAGE SCRIPT


});
```

[Link to live site](http://mike-griffin.com/test/index.html)

Comment: In this scenario try using jQuery noConflict.

Comment: @stanze: [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) is useful when jQuery is used next to another JS library that also work with `$`

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery.noConflict ... I got an answer that explained the problem to me. thanks though, i'll look into jquery no conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no element with class name *amoraeWork* on your main page, so this code:

```
$('.amoraeWork').offset().top
```

trying to access *offset()* returns undefined and trying to access *top* on undefined produces an error. The code following it is not executed (same happens with elements present on main page and missing from work).

You should check if an element is present, before accessing it’s *offset()* and *top* values:

```
  if($('.amoraeWork').length && wScroll > $('.amoraeWork').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 12 )) { 
        // do work here
  }
```

Comment: Ah I see!! I've changed it around and used an empty class named section-trigger and used it to trigger the parallax. So if there is an error halfway through the jquery will it not execute anything following the error? I haven't uploaded the working version yet but it's working, thank you!!

Comment: _So if there is an error halfway through the jquery will it not execute anything following the error?_ <-- Yes, unhandled exceptions terminate script execution in JavaScript (this is not jQuery specific).

Comment: I was to lazy to go through the live codes but nice catch . deleting my post and giving you +1. good work.

Comment: @kaarel , sorry to bother you again. So does it essentially mean that if I want to manipulate a class using jQuery and then I create a new page and make new classes and want to manipulate them also, I must include the class name on both pages? thanks again!

Comment: @ironmike No, luckily it doesn’t. jQuery methods on empty sets do not produce errors, they just don’t do anything (eg _$('.nonExistantClass').addClass('foo').hide()_). You were however asking for a property from a non-existant jQuery element, which returned _undefined_ and trying to access a property (_top_) on _undefined_ was what caused the error.

Comment: @ironmike ...and even if doing something that would cause an error on non-existant elements, you shouldn’t add unneeded class names on page but just check if an element existis (like I showed in an example above).

Comment: @kaarel I understand what you're saying. I've just done what you suggested and it worked perfectly. Just so I understand. the " if($('.amorae-work').length && wScroll >" - basically means if '.amorae-work' is there carry out function and the '.length' checks if it's there? Sorry if i'm a pain, I'm just starting to learn jQuery as you can guess. Also looking at the code can you recommend a more intelligent way of writing it so as i'm not repeating myself? Thank you so much I've learned quite a lot from you today :) it's very much appreciated

Comment: @ironmike _if($('.amorae-work').length && wScroll >" - basically means if '.amorae-work' is there carry out function and the '.length' checks if it's there?_ Exactly. As jQuery doesn’t return _null_  or _undefined_ even for queries for non-existant  elements, the standard way to make sure an element was found, is to check jQuery object’s length.

Comment: @ironmike As for organizing the code: the first step would be to avoid redundant checks and also store properties you are querying in multiple places to variables. See [some examples in this codepen](http://codepen.io/kaarel/pen/QbwWWw?editors=101)

Comment: @kaarel Aw that’s brilliant. I’m starting to understand it so much more. I used the codepen and came up with this :

if(wScroll > logoTop - (wHeight / 10)) {
    $('.about h1').addClass('about-h1-is-showing');
    }